# How to uninstall an app when "Uninstall" dialog is not shown?

Tags: applications, uninstallation

How to uninstall this app where after clicking uninstall, only the picture of the app shows up and there's no "OK, cancel" prompt?

My device is Asus Zenfone 2 Laser 5.5 (ZE550KL).

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Find the app from settings > apps /app information (varies as per Android version) and uninstall from there

Comment: That's the problem. After clicking uninstall it should show the prompt "Do you want to uninstall this app" with Ok or Cancel, but in my case just the picture above only being shown

Comment: See this answer by Firelord https://android.stackexchange.com/a/176249/131553

Comment: And avoid installing apps from "the wild wild web". You never know what you get (as seen). Use safe sources, such as F-Droid.

Comment: @Izzy ... or submit the .apk to VirusTotal before installing.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman that's one possible measure. But is it enough? Even for my repo I use multiple scanner (including VT) to see what's inside. And at F-Droid we only use that as *indicator* and do not trust the compiled APKs from "3rd parties" – not even libraries, all must be source for us to check and compile. You should only install from 3rd parties if you know what you're doing – and if you can help yourself in case you caught something.

Comment: @Izzy It's not enough, but it's better that nothing for the Android layman who can't/doesn't want to run a scanner on an .apk.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman it's better to wrap an axe in thick paper if you don't know how to handle it – but then, you shoiuldn't use it in the first place :) // 'nough said, we ain't no forum :)

Answer (score 2):

Boot into [safe-mode](/questions/tagged/safe-mode), go into Settings → Applications/Apps → find your app and uninstall it. This would work unless your device is a system app.

If it is a system app, disable it from Settings app. If you don't get the option to disable it, and you're certain that disabling it would not affect the stability of your Android (think of boot loops and crashes), then enable [usb-debugging](/questions/tagged/usb-debugging), setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb), and issue either of these commands:

```
adb shell pm disable-user PACKAGE_NAME         # disables the app         
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 PACKAGE_NAME   # uninstalls the app for primary user account
```

Replace PACKAGE_NAME with the package name of the troublesome app. To  get help in finding it, see my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/198095/96277).