# A non-existing app keeps crashing

Tags: applications, force-stop, non-market

I've removed an app long ago, but when I unlock the phone a message appears which says: "the app" has stopped

I had changed its location from internal to external before I remove it.

Also I have another app which keep stopping, I changed it to external too.

I cannot rechange the apps which I changed their location after I've updated  android system

These two apps are not English

J7 prime 2017
Android 8.1.0

Comment: Try installing the app again and then uninstall

Comment: Still apears , and about the other problems?

Comment: One problem at a time is a better approach. Try uninstall following this answer https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204485/131553. Also [edit] to add device details and Android version

Comment: Didnt work. This app is not in my application list at all!

Comment: I would try finding the folder where the app was installed and deleting the files there after it is uninstalled.  It sounds like it is not removing the actual program completely.

Comment: Thank you but I've tried this way and I didnt folind the folder

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, a corrupted cache can make the system behave unexpectedly.

So, try clearing the cache partition from the recovery mode on android. It solves most issues.

Comment: Didnt work... you know, sometimes it appeares and then after a restart it disappears! Now it is not appearing after unlocking but maybe after one restart or max power saving mode, it is begining its bothering

Comment: What was the app and what type of app was it?

Comment: A non-english application (kind a book), also I have problem with these kind application.

Comment: Did you install it from play store ?

Comment: Nope. Of course

Comment: Go to Developer settings->Running services. Check whether that app is running in the background or not. If that app is found, it means that it was not completely removed from storage.

Comment: I found it, now how I should uninstall it completelly?

Comment: Click on that app in running services list, then click on the 'Force stop' button. Then restart your device.

Comment: Didnt work  I want u check this out https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ap0XhcNArOiBgUpe3QVPr3NSN5DO

Comment: Sorry, I can't see it because I am working on Jio phone. And I do not have any other device. Can you say what is it?

Comment: Yeah, I turned it off in the 'check background' menu, but it becomes on again when I come back to it. Even I try restart

Comment: Are you sure that the app is not listed in the applications list?

Comment: I am pretty sure, even in developer settings>inactivate apps you can not find the app! The only place I found it is the "check background" list! Even there is no folder of the app. I am really tired

Comment: You can root your device and manually remove the app's installed files. OR, if you want a hassle free way, you can perform a FACTORY RESET.

Comment: 

Comment: Now we are talking. It was just because of secure folder. It contains many deleted apps( but in its own way)