# Does OnePlus support removing NetFlix?

Tags: bloatware, oxygenos, netflix, oneplus-7

I noticed that my new OnePlus 7 Pro has Netflix preinstalled. This is awkward being the phone is so much more than prior models, and OnePlus has always prided itself on not shipping bloatware. Is it possible to remove Netflix from the app-list and as an installed application without rooting the phone? I have the option to *Force Stop* and *Disable*, but neither of them give me the ability to uninstall,

[image: NEtflix App Info]

[I see Netflix and OnePlus announced a partnership in 2019.](https://media.netflix.com/en/press-releases/netflix-partners-with-oneplus) Does that mean we're locked into having Netflix stuff installed on OxygenOS?

Comment: Why not just disable it? Space isn't typically an issue in modern high end phones, and in most cases if you "uninstall" system bloatware it is really just hiding it anyway because it returns on a factory reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That screenshot suffices to say that the Netflix app is a permanent bloatware. A permanent bloatware has Disable option instead of Uninstall option. Furthermore, it is not the only bloatware. Many folks consider Google apps as a bloatware too. Regardless, your only choice to get rid of that bloatware permanently is to root the device and delete its APK. Otherwise,  because Disable option is available it should work for non-roted users. However, If you are keen to uninstall the app without root, you can use [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) but do know that the app would return after a factory reset. Follow the link [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204485/96277) for that method.