# how to uninstall beta gcamera app downloaded from unknown installation source for samsung galaxy a50s (SM-A507FN)

Tags: samsung, uninstallation, android-10

I have a new phone. Samsung Galaxy A50s. Model number SM-A507FN
https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a50s-9806.php

I downloaded `Arnova's Beta 6: GCam_5beta6.200105.0445build-7.2.018.apk`

for Android 9+ phones from https://www.celsoazevedo.com/files/android/google-camera/dev-suggested/
assuming it will work on my phone. However, the app has been crashing frequently and it does not work.
I have upgraded the software of the phone so it was upgraded to `Android 10. Kernel 4.14.62-17887617.`

This app was not installed from playstore so I don't know how to uninstall it now.
So please let me know how to uninstall this app.

Comment: Does it not appear in the list of installed apps either in settings or in the app drawer?

Comment: no it does not appear in settings, and play store.

Comment: Please see this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204485/131553). The package name of your Arnova is `com. goggle. Android. GoogleCamera`. But I am **not sure** if this approach will be safe. Just pointing out a possibility