# how to improve performance for games?

Tags: performance, google-play-games, quick-responses

When touch responsiveness is really important (other than urgent moments, actually that would be a more important context).

I have a sm-j700, android 6.0.1, 1.34GB RAM (low RAM is the biggest problem).

To play games like pubg mobil elite, or AnimA ARPG, I have to:

- clean google play services app bloatful data (seems to cause generic overall slowdown, why they dont fix it?)
- disable OS animations in developer mode
- disable the weather forecast widget and set its update interval to none, that app is really problematic

Edit: disable or uninstall (adb shell remove) most apps that insist on using RAM, was what really worked here. Use simple system monitor to track'em. Use system safe app remover for hints on what you can uninstall.

And I always have to:

- developer mode: stop all services using too much memory >= 10MB (least google play services and anything else you think is important like a firewall), and weather forecast app if it ever believes I need it running and causing trouble (sometimes I have to do this again while playing the game). And the only way to stop "samsung push service" from auto restarting is going to it's info and force stop it.
- quickly start the game after that to grant it will use RAM before the annoying bloatful services have a chance to mess it up

If I don't do that, suddenly touches are ignored, the game freezes for many seconds, touches freezes and the game keeps playing like we are holding the touch, and worst of all, the OS may crash and reboot...

But all that is quite a lot of micromanagement lowering the quality of the android realm user experience making people everywere complaint, when it is actually easily fixable.

Are there other tips I am missing?

Could all that be automatic on a non rooted phone? Like a generic game launcher that grants all is perfect before running the game?

But if it could work only on rooted, I would consider doing that.

Should I split this making an answer? Did it work on your phone model and android version?

Comment: The only thing you could try is permanently disable the weather widget app as shown [hre](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204485/2241). Besides that I think you have to face reality. You can't teach an old dog new tricks, means your phone is near end-of-life if you want to play games.

Comment: Agreed! But new phones in my country are are unnecessarily costy because of my country's low valued currency worsened by import and transaction taxes. Basically, we here end with no much choice than stick with old but good phones and beg developers to not bloat the games with non optional and mostly unnecessary assets.

Comment: Then may be you should root/unlock your device and install a clean custom ROM without any Google services and the typical Samsung junk. Then you would have to install updates manually but it would allow you to run the device with a minimum OS so you could get a maximum of RAM and no interference form services running in background. For custom ROMs check XDA: https://forum.xda-developers.com/f/samsung-galaxy-j7-roms-kernels-recoveries-oth.5266/

Comment: I didnt know we could remove google services completely! I will consider that, thx! Non rooted is difficult to have quality, and they clearly depreciate old phones (by not providing updates for ex) to sell new hardware, what is not compatible with the reality of 3rd world countries.