# Cant install apps from Play store or using APK file and MIUI storage calculates 0 free space

Tags: installation, storage, apk, mi

First time asking so please correct me if I am wrong,Also please suggest me title for this question

I have redmi 8 running miui 12 , Recently I cant install apps from playstore it keeps pending and after a while it show storage full . But I have plenty of space about 30GB out of 64GB . And when I try to install apk file , the package manager stop with a black screen and nothing happens .

I checked mobile storage and it display only "/"
[image: miui about phone setting page show / in storage no values]

After I click on storage it take about 4 minutes to calculate storage and then show actual storage that is "33gb/64Gb"
[![mi storage calculating storage][2]][2]

Edit -
The mobile also hangs a lot and it ram usage get high .  1 gb left out of 4gb
I tried debugging using adb and found that installd and system-server were consuming ram like 48% and 42%

[image]

Edit 2 - tried debugging (user app list generated by adebar)
https://pastebin.pl/view/91afe4ff

Comment: The second picture is the initialized screen (before calculation). Something is broken, it should not take more than few seconds to calculate. Does it ever finish? Also the first picture should show disk usage immediately. Maybe you have malicious app which you should uninstall. A factory reset is your last option to fix

Comment: @alecxs I also think something broken , 2. Yes , it finish but it takes 3-4 minutes to calculate storage ,How I can identify the malicious  app I dont want to reset , I also updated second photo I took it too early so calculating was not shown

Comment: from PC via [adb](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) use [adebar](https://codeberg.org/izzy/Adebar) to get package list and check HTML file which user app is not available on google play store

Comment: @alecxs I created the list as you said but I cant figure out which app it is . Here can you have a look and help me  https://pastebin.pl/view/91afe4ff

Comment: I have checked there are 27 apps available in google play (11 not installed from google play). Mi Doc Viewer, Mi Credit, Amrit Kirtan Gutka are not available in google play (at least not with that package names)

Comment: you can try *'adb shell [pm disable-user](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203455) com.khalsa.AmritKirtan'* (or other packages) and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for your help , I will uninstall these apps They arent that important . I will update if found anything