# So, I have an app called "ww_easteur001", never installed it, and it behaves... weird I would say. Need help with it

Tags: applications, malware, unknown-sources, virus

So, I never installed this app, it just appeared at some point on my phone. I didn't do anything at first, thought it was something related to android because it has an android icon.

The problem is that sometimes, when I would of opened Chrome, it would of opened with a site already on it (something with some kind of clickbait game) and a **ww_easteur001** notification. Sometimes that notification just popped up without anything happening "apparently". I unistalled it a while ago, thought that it was gone, after a few weeks it appeared again. Uninstalled it again, appeared again, etc.

Today I looked closely and I saw that it had access to my Phone (calls and numbers), Messages and Storage, and I found out that at some point a message was sent to a number not in my contact list that seemed like pure gibberish. (My luck that I don't have credit atm, so the message didn't go through). I obviously suspected that app.

So... Need help. I'm not entirely sure what I should do (I know I should of done something the first time when I saw it, but I was dumb), I'm not sure what it does exactly, but definitely not something good. I cannot find anything online about it / similar experiences...

Now, worst case scenario I can just reset the phone and/or buy a new one, since this one is trash anyway, but I'm still confused about what's all this about, and I may or may not be a little bit scared to what it has done this whole time.

**EDIT:**

*Model number*: Xylo P

*Android version*: 7.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's definitely not an Android system app (or you wouldn't see the "uninstall" button). You could start by revoking its permissions (and see if they're "magically granted back" the next day). You could also simply uninstall it (and see if it comes magically back the next day). As you didn't install it yourself, some other app must be responsible for that (see e.g. [Unwanted apps auto installing without me doing anything. How to stop them?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/175494/16575))

Comment: FWIW, the Android icon is the default icon that Android Studio provides, so the "developer" didn't provide any icon for it. Please also consider mentioning the package name of this "app" by following [View app's full package name?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767/44325).

Comment: @Izzy "I unistalled it a while ago, thought that it was gone, after a few weeks it appeared again. Uninstalled it again, appeared again, etc." Yeah, already did that. I'll look to the link you sent, thank you!

Comment: The `=` as last character in the SMS often indicates base64 encoding. The decoded string is `�M4yo2s51blzvrbsmco5gqp`.